# Regex to match words and those with an apostrophe

Tags: regex, python-3.x

**Update**: As per comments regarding the ambiguity of my question, I've increased the detail in the question.

(Terminology: by words I am refering to any succession of *alphanumerical* characters.)

I'm looking for a regex to match the following, verbatim:

- Words.
- Words with *one* apostrophe at the beginning.
- Words with *any number of non-contiguous* apostrophe throughout the middle.
- Words with *one* apostrophe at the end.

I would like to match the following, however not verbatim, rather, removing the apostrophes:

- Words with an apostrophe at the beginning and at the end would be matched to the word, without the apostrophes. So `'foo'` would be matched to `foo`.
- Words with more than one contiguous apostrophe in the middle would be resolved to two different words: the fragment before the contiguous apostrophes and the fragment after the contiguous apostrophes. So, `foo''bar` would be matched to `foo` and `bar`.
- Words with more than one contiguous apostrophe at the beginning or at the end would be matched to the word, without the apostrophes. So, `''foo` would be matched to `foo` and `''foo''` to `foo`.

**Examples**
These would be matched verbatim:

- `'bout`
- `it's`
- `persons'`

But these would be ignored:

- `'`
- `''`

And, for `'open'`, `open` would be matched.

Comment: The question is not well defined. How words are delimited? How many apostrophes are allowed in a word? What should be the correct output for the example: 'how'about'this'one'.
Looking at the example of 'open', I doubt there is a solution without usage of lookahead/lookbehind.

Comment: @Ilia K., what's wrong with using lookahead/lookbehind?

Comment: I don't think you can have a single regex that matches 1 word, 2 words, 3 words, or N words. E.g., you could write something that works for `'foo'`, `''foo`, `bar''`, `foo'b`, but not something that works for `foo''bar`, `'foo''bar'`, `'foo'bar'zim`, at the same time.

Answer (score 23):

#### Try using this:

`(?=.*\w)^(\w|')+$`

```
'bout     # pass
it's      # pass
persons'  # pass
'         # fail
''        # fail
```

#### Regex Explanation

```
NODE      EXPLANATION
  (?=       look ahead to see if there is:
    .*        any character except \n (0 or more times
              (matching the most amount possible))
    \w        word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
  )         end of look-ahead
  ^         the beginning of the string
  (         group and capture to \1 (1 or more times
            (matching the most amount possible)):
    \w        word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
   |         OR
    '         '\''
  )+        end of \1 (NOTE: because you're using a
            quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
            repetition of the captured pattern will be
            stored in \1)
  $         before an optional \n, and the end of the
            string
```

Comment: Cheers on the explanation too.

Comment: This is great! How would I "eat" the last character if it is punctuation, e.g., "ebooks." becomes "ebooks", "thus," becomes "thus"?

Comment: Regex101 doesn't match anything in the sentence: These are a few words. I will type more words later, like pat.omes@att.net and I'm out of here. 'Here' is another word

Answer (score 4):

```
/('\w+)|(\w+'\w+)|(\w+')|(\w+)/
```

- **'\w+** Matches a ' followed by one or more alpha characters, OR
- **\w+'\w+** Matche sone or more alpha characters  followed by a ' followed by one or more alpha characters, OR
- **\w+'** Matches one or more alpha characters followed by a '
- **\w+** Matches one or more alpha characters

Comment: Returns `'a` for `'a'` (should return `a`) but otherwise great.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
'?\b[0-9A-Za-z']+\b'?
```

EDIT: the previous version doesn't include apostrophes on the sides.

Comment: @shinkou, this matches `'` and `''` as well. The OP doesn't want it to match if there are not letters present.

Comment: @smotchkkiss: are you sure it match ' or ''? Just tested it and seems to work well

Comment: hey, my fault the down vote. Was playing with the arrows, could you edit your post so I can revert it?

Comment: @Claudio It's ok.  I just wanted to share what I know.

Comment: no, but I didn't mean to downvote you, it was an accident. But now it doesn't allow me to revert it. If you edit your post I would be able to do it. Sorry :-(

Comment: @shinkou, the edit is nice. Per the OP's updated question you might want to change the `'?` expressions to `'*` to match `''foo`, or `bar''`.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted this 2nd answer coz it looks like the question has changed quite a bit and my previous answer is no longer valid.  Anyway, if all conditions are listed up, try this:

```
(((?<!')')?\b[0-9A-Za-z]+\b('(?!'))?|\b[0-9A-Za-z]+('[0-9A-Za-z]+)*\b)
```

Comment: apostrophe missed

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
 ('*)(?:'')*('?(?:\w+'?)+\w+('\b|'?[^']))(\1)
```

on this data no problem

```
    'bou
    it's
    persons'
    'open'
    open
    foo''bar
    ''foo
    bee''
    ''foo''
    '
    ''
```

on this data you should strip result (remove spaces from matches)

```
    'bou it's persons' 'open' open foo''bar ''foo ''foo'' ' ''
```

(tested in The Regulator, results in $2)