# Regular expression to match exact string with apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to write regular expressions to match these exact strings:

- "i'm in"
- "i'm out"

i'm not searching for a single character. i'm searching for an exact string and trying to understand how reg exs work.

i've read the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) docs and the [chapter](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html) in Eloquent JS, as well as searched on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596893/regex-to-match-words-and-those-with-an-apostrophe) conversations.

i understand that anything in square brackets represents a character set and the characters do not have to occur in a sequence.

i tried `/[i\'m] in/` which works in my code but when i run:

`/[i\'m] in/.exec('i\'m in')` it evaluates to ["m in"]

i also tried `/i\'m in/` which doesn't work in my code and when but when i run:

`/i\'m in/.exec('i\'m in')` it evaluates to ["i'm in"]

not sure why this is so. any pointers or illuminations would be great.

Comment: The apostrophe character is not special in regular expressions. You don't have to quote or escape it. `/i'm (in|out)/` should do it. If you want to match those *complete* exact strings, `/^i'm (in|out)$/`

Comment: Also the `.exec()` function returns an array of matched pattern parts. Your last example is working properly. What did you expect it to return?

Comment: If you want to see what a regular expression matches, you could play with http://www.regexpal.com/

Comment: If you want to match those strings you could use the expression `/^i'm (in|out)$/` where the ^ anchors the string at the start of the string and $ at the end of the string.

Comment: The [] is used to specify what characters should match (or not match) and can be a range, for example `[a-f]` matches ONE character in the string, if it is a lowercase a, b, c, d, e or f. `[a-f]{2}` can be used to match TWO characters, like `aa`, `bc` or `fa`. `[0-9a-fAF]{2}` matches any two-digit hexadecimal value, regardless of case, example: `0a`, `F3` or `Bc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches only 4 characters while your complete string is 6 characters long.

```
/[i\'m] in/.exec('i\'m in')
```

Regex --> `[i\'m] in`

It will match 4 characters. The first character can be either `i` or `\'` or `m`. The second character is a `space` and third character is `i` and fourth character is `n`. You don't have to use `\` for `'` in regex. But you will need to use `\` for `'` in JS string.

String --> `'i\'m in'`
`m in` is the string the regex matches.
It can also match these strings:
`i in`, `' in`

If you want to match all 6 characters of string you can use something like this:

```
/i'm in/.exec('i\'m in')
```

Demo: https://repl.it/EfDS/3

And if you want to match either in or out, you can use an `or` operator.

```
/i'm (in|out)/.exec('i\'m out')
```

Demo: https://repl.it/EfDS/4

Comment: Thanks so much. This helps a lot.

Comment: Why are you using `[i\'m]{3}` ?? That's not what the person who wrote the question wanted. It matches `iii`, `ii'`, `iim`, `i'i`, `i''`, `i'm`, `imi`, `im'`, `imm`, `'ii`, `'i'`, `'im`, `''i`, `'''`, `''m`, `'mi`, `'m'`, `'mm`, `mii`, `mi'`, `mim`, `m'i`, `m''`, `m'm`, `mmi`, `mm'` and `mmm`. What the person wanted was something like `/^i'm (in|out)$/`

Comment: Yes you are right. I'll correct it. But the point of emphasis was that his regex was matching only 4 characters. Thanks.

Comment: I disagree. The poster was trying to learn and did a mistake with the syntax. You answer has now made the poster believe that's the way it should be done.

Comment: Ok I agree with you. But he learned about length though :). Now he will crash his regex somewhere and comeback again to learn why not to use []{3}. And I learned from you to address all the points :).